# Generate .click functions inside for loop

Tags: javascript, loops

Inside my for loop that loops through 15 "box" objects, code below:

```
for (var i = 0; i < boxesLength; i++) {
```

I'm trying to generate these click events automatically, they used to be like this: (all the way up until 15)

```
$("#box0").click(function(){
    var rw = 462;
    var input = $('#rw');
    input.val(rw);

    var rh = 310;
    var input = $('#rh');
    input.val(rh);
    calculateRectangle();
    calculateRectangle2();
});
```

Right now I am trying to auto-generate these in the for loop by doing this:

```
$("#box" + i).click(function(){
    var rw = allBoxes[i].width;
    var input = $('#rw');
    input.val(rw);

    var rh = allBoxes[i].length;
    var input = $('#rh');
    input.val(rh);
    calculateRectangle();
    calculateRectangle2();
});
```

What am I doing wrong? When I console log "#box" + i I am getting the expected result..

Comment: Why are you setting 15 different event listeners to the boxes, instead of setting just 1 to a common ancestor and delegating it to them? Your code becomes extremely repetitive that way.

Answer (score 1):

This is an exemple of `closures`. When you're trying to click one button then your alghorithm will use the last value of `i` variable which is `boxesLength`.

To solve this, just use `let`keyword.

```
for (let i = 0; i < boxesLength; i++) {
     ^^^
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution will be like this:

```
$("#box" + i).click(function(i){
return function(){
    var rw = allBoxes[i].width;
    var input = $('#rw');
    input.val(rw);

    var rh = allBoxes[i].length;
    var input = $('#rh');
    input.val(rh);
    calculateRectangle();
    calculateRectangle2();
}}(i));
```